# Braintree-javascript - collect additional customer information?

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal, transactions, braintree

**Question is:What is the correct way for collecting customer information and storing it in the vault?**

I want to store customer's billing information in Braintree's vault upon filling out and submitting the drop-in ui form for the purpose of creating periodic future transactions. Future transactions will have irregular/varied amounts being charged.

Currently the drop-in ui I have configured only has a paypal button and input fields for cc # and expiration date. This is what I currently have for drop-in ui:

[image: Drop-in ui I have configured]

According to the [docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/javascript/v2), Braintree drop-in ui only allows collecting: cc#, exp date, postal code/cvv, paypal acc, and venmo acc.

I was thinking something along the lines of creating a form and collecting from input fields using jquery and feeding it to Braintree's [transaction API](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/transactions/node), but not sure this is PCI/SAQ-A compliant. I also found that I can [store a new customer in the vault upon a successful transaction](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/node#storing-in-vault).

[image: Work in progress form]

Code looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="checkout" method="post" action="/checkout">

    <!-- billing information -->
    <div class="container" style="width: 50%">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="Full Name">Full Name:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" placeholder="Full Name">
          </div>
        <br>
          <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="Address">Address:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Address" placeholder="Address">
          </div>
        <br>
        zip | city
        <br>
        country
      </div>
    </div>
      <hr>
      <!-- braintree drop-in ui form-->
      <div class="text-center" id="payment-form"></div>

      <!-- TOS -->
      <div class="container">
        <h4>TOS Place holder</h4>
        This will be where the TOS goes. It's a pretty good space is it not?
        <br>
        <h4>TOS Place holder</h4>
        This will be where the TOS goes. It's a pretty good space is it not?
        <br>
        <h4>TOS Place holder</h4>
        This will be where the TOS goes. It's a pretty good space is it not?
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="text-center">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Payment" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- braintree sdk -->
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>

<!-- braintree setup -->
<script>

/*
* Uncomment when no longer in sandbox
*/
//Get client token
// $.get( "/client_token", function(clientToken) {
//   braintree.setup(clientToken, 'dropin', {
//     container: 'payment-form'
//   });
// });


var clientToken = *removed*;
braintree.setup(
    // Replace this with a client token from your server
    clientToken,
    "dropin", {
      container: "payment-form",
      form: "checkout",
    });
</script>
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to [contact support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sup>

The Braintree Drop-in UI is responsible for collecting PCI and other sensitive payment information. The approach you mentioned, collecting billing information in a form and then submitting the billing information to Braintree via API from your server (using [transaction.sale](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/node) or [paymentMethod.create](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/create/node)), is the correct approach for populating this information. This approach is fully PCI compliant.

Additionally, passing the `form` attribute to `braintree.setup` is not necessary in your example because your `payment-form` div is within your `checkout` form.